# Populate child object in Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to populate child object from below json on basis of parent id, but facing some issue, I need your help here. I am new in Json so please suggest  me some solution, I wand to show child1, child2 child3 if page id is 2, I am trying to populate child object from below json on basis of parent id, but facing some issue, I need your help here. I am new in Json so please suggest  me some solution, I wand to show child1, child2 child3 if page id is 2

```
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "slug": "parent",
        "title": "Parent",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "id": "12",
                "slug": "child1",
                "title": "child1"
            },
            {
                "id": "14",
                "slug": "child2",
                "title": "child2"
            },
            {
                "id": "15",
                "slug": "child3",
                "title": "child3"
            },
            {
                "id": "16",
                "slug": "child4",
                "title": "child4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "slug": "parent2",
        "title": "Parent2",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "id": "32",
                "slug": "child1",
                "title": "child1"
            },
            {
                "id": "33",
                "slug": "child2",
                "title": "child3"
            }
        ]
    }
]

[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "slug": "parent",
        "title": "Parent",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "id": "12",
                "slug": "child1",
                "title": "child1"
            },
            {
                "id": "14",
                "slug": "child2",
                "title": "child2"
            },
            {
                "id": "15",
                "slug": "child3",
                "title": "child3"
            },
            {
                "id": "16",
                "slug": "child4",
                "title": "child4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "slug": "parent2",
        "title": "Parent2",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "id": "32",
                "slug": "child1",
                "title": "child1"
            },
            {
                "id": "33",
                "slug": "child2",
                "title": "child3"
            }
        ]
    }
]

$.getJSON("data.json" , function(json) {
    $.each(json,function(i, value){
        $.each(value.subcategories, function(index, obj){
            $('#list-category-slider').append('<div class="item"><a href="/' + obj.slug + '">' + obj.title + '</a></div>');
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry typo mistake, it will be child

Comment: Your code works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, filter array to get current page based on id. And iterate over the properties to create the list. For test, pageId is set to 2.

```js
  $(function(){
  var json =
 [
  {
   "id": "2",
   "slug": "parent",
   "title": "Parent",
   "subcategories": [
    {
     "id": "12",
     "slug": "child1",
     "title": "child1"
    },
    {
     "id": "14",
     "slug": "child2",
     "title": "child2"
    },
    {
     "id": "15",
     "slug": "child3",
     "title": "child3"
    },
    {
     "id": "16",
     "slug": "child4",
     "title": "child4"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "11",
   "slug": "parent2",
   "title": "Parent2",
   "subcategories": [
    {
     "id": "32",
     "slug": "child1",
     "title": "child1"
    },
    {
     "id": "33",
     "slug": "child2",
     "title": "child3"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]

 var pageId = 2;
 var currentPage = json.filter(function(el){
  return el.id == pageId;
 })[0]; 
 $.each(currentPage.subcategories, function(index, obj){
  $('#list-category-slider').append('<div class="item"><a href="/' + obj.slug + '">' + obj.title + '</a></div>');
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='list-category-slider'>

</div>
```

Comment: Please accept the answer and also remove duplicate items from json and question itself.